# Anova-post hoc-no normal distribution

Tags: r, anova, posthoc

i want to apply Anova to a no-normal response variable, verify if residuals are normal and use post-hocs.How can i make it?

Comment: Transform the endpoint or choose a non-parametric test rather than a parametric one. Then run the code.

Comment: have a go, show us your code, and we'll help you.